# Typescript baseUrl not resolving in build folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a simple Typescript node app that works in dev mode but when I run a build, it doesn't seem to convert the baseUrl and paths correctly.

```js
// index.ts

import config from "@/config"; // this lives in `src/config.ts`

console.log("config:", config)
```

My tsconfig is as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2021",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "integration/**/*", "src/types.d.ts", "./global.d.ts"]
}
```

I can then run a successful `npm run build` but then running `npm run start` throws an error: `Error: Cannot find module '@/config'`. When I check the build file, it is still showing the imports / requires with `@` in them like so:

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const config_1 = __importDefault(require("@/config")); // I believe this should be the relative path
console.log("config:", config_1.default);
```

My NPM scripts are as follows:

```json
{ 
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production && tsc --project tsconfig.build.json",
    "dev": "nodemon -r tsconfig-paths/register -r dotenv/config --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js"
  }
}
```

How do I configure Typescript to convert my imports to replace the baseUrl paths to the correct ones that Javascript will understand?